# how to disable tx-checksum-ipv4 which is fixed

Tags: networking

i want to disable tx-checksum-ipv4 with the ethtool
this is the output of

```
ethtool -k eth0
Features for eth0:
rx-checksumming: off [fixed]
tx-checksumming: on
    tx-checksum-ipv4: on [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather: on [fixed]
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
    tx-tcp-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off [fixed]
udp-fragmentation-offload: off [fixed]
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-offload: off [fixed]
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: off [fixed]
highdma: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
```

the tx-checksum-ipv4 is on ,and i want to disable it with

```
ethtool -K eth0 tx-checksum-ipv4 off
```

i got

```
Could not change any device features
```

i want to know how to disable this tx-checksum-ipv4.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** the network driver you are using should implement an option to disable tx-checksum-ipv4, otherwise it would be set to the default state on driver load and marked as '[fixed]'.

**More Information:** First, each feature support is defined by a macro under include/linux/netdev-features.h and tx-checksum-ipv4 is defined by NETIF_F_IP_CSUM. Each driver set its default feature support so if NETIF_F_IP_CSUM is included tx-checksum-ipv4 will be enabled by default.

As far as I can tell, most of the sub options for TX checksum (ipv4, ipv6, etc.) aren't exposed by themselves. You can try disabling TX checksum completely if it is possible in your case, which should disable the offload for all cases. You'll see the actual changes when changing the state:

```
ethtool -K ens4f0 tx on
Actual changes:
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
```

As you can see not only the supported inner TX checksum changes, but also related offloads.

It is a bit hard to give an exact answer without the driver vendor and version. Please specify more information on future questions.